# In the new Google Photos API (Sep 2018), does the discovery API return uploads() as an endpoint?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-photos-api

I am using the Google API client in Python3.

All the examples always go about using discovery.build to create a service and then perform actions using that.

So... I don't think uploads as described here are possible simply using the API.  Is that right?

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/discovery/v1/discovery.apis.getRest?api=photoslibrary&version=v1&_h=2&

Is the way folks solve this by making a request and not relying upon the google API client?

Comment: Why do you think `uploads()` should be an endpoint in the Python client? `uploads()` isn't a thing in the REST API: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/ . Did you mean `batchCreate` and `create`? Those are the endpoints that let you create things.

Comment: From a quick check of the Photos API docs, it doesn't seem like the relevant support for the Python client library has been added yet - just the Java and PHP clients: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/client-libraries - which means you'll need to make authorized HTTP calls and do the grunt work yourself https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media#uploading-bytes

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52038045/9337071 for some Python code that should get you started, or at least help you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52674334/edit) this question to be answerable

Comment: Yes I agree that there is a workaround.  The Google Photos API website says to file issues here, I think... so I'm hoping this is enough info for them.  You're right it looks like it's in the other clients.

Comment: No, file an issue on the actual client library repo (on GitHub). This isn't a feature tracker for Google *anything*.